# How to use CXF soap servlet aside spring REST servlet?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I'm providing a `soap` webservice with java-first approach, thus using `CXF` for this. To make it publishing with `spring-boot`, I have the following dispatcher servlet:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
    return registration;
}
```

This works fine, but I now want to offer a `REST` service aside. The rest service should NOT be published by cxf, but by the default spring mapping:

```
@RestConstroller
@RequestMapping("/rest/content")
public class MyServiceRest extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

}
```

The result of this:

- `localhost:8080/app-name/rest/content` results in HTTP 404.
- `localhost:8080/app-name/services/rest/content` shows a spring message `"No service was found."`

So, somehow the latter is inside the context of the `CXFServlet`, and the REST service is not found.

What do I have to change to make this setup work?

By the way: when I remove the `ServletRegistrationBean`, the rest service works as expected. But that's not an option as I have to offer the soap service alongside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bean named `dispatcherServletRegistration` is replacing Spring Boot's default `DispatcherServlet` so your left with just a `CXFServlet` and no `DispatcherServlet` in your application.

Update your bean to register the `CXFServlet` to something like this:

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServletRegistration() {
     return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
}
```